# BOTO3 only returning only returning partial data from DynamoDB Table

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have a relatively simple DynamoDB table that has a date string as the partition key, a name as a sort key, and a text representation of a JSON document as an attribute named Document.

I'm querying it with this code:

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('SolarData')

response = table.get_item(
    Key={'StartDate': '2019-07-08', 'InverterName': 'Inverter1'},
)

print(response)
```

The problem that I'm having is that the response only has about the first 10K bytes of the Document which is about 50K bytes long.

I know that the entire document data is stored as I can see it in the AWS Console and also if I do a get-item from the CLI with this command:

```
aws dynamodb get-item --table-name SolarData --key "{""StartDate"":{""S"":""2019-07-10""},""InverterName"":{""S"":""Inverter1""}}"
```

I get the entire document written to the output.  So I think the problem is either in my code, like I'm not handling the response correctly, or there is a bug in BOTO3.

I searched through the issues list on the BOTO3 GitHub project but didn't find anything that seemed relevant to this.

Comment: I checked the documentation and they do: item = response['Item']  --> print(item). I'd check the length and see if the response is a data structure of some type.

Comment: response['Item'] exhibits the same behavior.  Only the first part of it is present in the output.

Comment: @mgrollins That wasn't the issue but doing a print(len(response['Item']['Document'])) was informative.  It printed 41910!  So I think the real issue is with Python's print() function that must have some limit to how long a string it will print.  If you want to post that as an answer I'll accept it since your hint got me past this problem.

Comment: Great @jwh20! I'll post it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is data in your response, then result should be a data structure with an "Item" key. Test for that key.

Since you are able to print some of the result, and after consulting the docs, I would try some introspection at a REPL if you can.

```
item = response['Item']
dir(item)
len(item)
print(json.dumps(item, indent=4))
```

I have found these examinations help me get my head around what was returned from an unfamiliar API.